# Identifying a group from its child groupitems

Tags: excel, vba, parent-child, shapes

On a spreadsheet there are groups of shapes conected to one another. In my application I´m looping through the connectors to identify the shapes connected to it´s tips. I can succesfully get the groupitem but I cannot get the group object. Could anyone help me

```
       For Each shp In ws.Shapes

           If (shp.AutoShapeType = -2) Then  'test if shape is a connector
                i = i + 1
                With shp.ConnectorFormat
                         Set a = .BeginConnectedShape
                         Set b = .EndConnectedShape
                         Set c = .BeginConnectedShape.Parent 'doesn´t work
                 End With

                '.....more code, processing of the colected data....'

           End If
       Next shp
```

Comment: I don't think you should have such a problem. Read up on connectors here: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s394/lines-connectors.htm. Observe the `RerouteConnections` method mentioned at the end. The theory explained there is that a connector has an object at its beginning and another at its end - hard to say which ob these objects is dominant, and no identifiable "group".

Comment: Thanks for the link braX its very good general text for dealing with shapes.  Neveetheless  it does not address the exact necessity.   I can succesfully retrive the shapes connected to any connector using: "BeginConnectedShape" and  "EndConnectedShape"   but,  my objects are groupes shapes, and it brings the groupitem only.  I need to also be able to retrieve the group to which the shape item belong.

Comment: So the problem reduces to:  given an shape groupitem (child object) how to find the group (parent) to which it belongs.

Comment: In a group of shapes there are only members, no children and no parent. Members of a group are identified by a common group name. Connectors are themselves shapes. If you have joined all connectors around a, say, rectangle by a common  group name you can find the rectangle by searching through all shapes with the Connector's group name for the one which is of Rectangle type.

Comment: Thanks, but the picture is a little bit different.  Supose I have on a spreadsheet 2 shape groups, lets call them group1 and group2 their groupitems are simple rectangles.  Now I draw a connector, connecting one groupitem (rectangle4) of the group 1 to another groupitem of the group2 (rectangle5). The connector is not part of any group.   By looping through the conectors and using the method "BeginConnectedShape" and "EndConnectedShape" I can retrieve the shapes: rectangle4 and rectangle 5, but I need to also retrieve the groups to which such objects belong,  that is "group1" and "group2".

Comment: .... and this seems not to work using: "BeginConnectedShape.ParentGroup",  and this is what I can't understand.   If you check this link, it seems that this is exctly what the method "ParentGroup" should do.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.parentgroup

Comment: Once you have one member of the group you can list the other members using the `GroupItem` peroperty explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.groupitems

Comment: Thanks Variatus, but the point is to identify the group (father) from one of its groupitems.  Its not really the same case as the example.

Comment: I have actually found a solution to my need spending a little bit more code and, of course processing time.  I looped through all the connectors and found the groupitem connected to its ends, retrived the ID of such groupitens shapes,  then I looped through all grouped shapes and for each one I looped for each of its groupitens untill I found a matching shape ID.   It would have been a lot easier if there was a way to retrive the group shape from its groupitems instead of going through all these loops,  but it worked.